# If $\tau_1\subset\tau_2$ then $K_2(A)\subset K_1(A)$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a set. We define a Kuratowski operator as a map $K : \mathcal{P}(X) \longrightarrow \mathcal{P}(X)$  that satisfies:

- $K(\emptyset) = \emptyset$.
- $A \subset K(A), \: \forall A \subset X$.
- $K(K(A)) = K(A), \: \forall A \subset X$.
- $K(A) \cup K(B) = K(A \cup B), \: \forall A, B \subset X$.

I need to prove the following:

> Let $\tau_1 \subset \tau_2$ be two topologies and let $K_1, K_2$ be two Kuratowski operators that induce its closures. Prove that $K_2(A) \subset K_1(A), \: \forall A \subset X$.

This is what I have done so far:

If $U\in \tau_1$ then $U\in \tau_2$ since $\tau_1\subset\tau_2$. Therefore, $X\setminus U$ is a closed set in both $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$.

I also know that a set is closed if and only if $K(A)=A$

I don't know what to do next, could someone please help me?

Comment: Hint: What is the definition of a closure? You can think of the complement of $K_1(A)$. Is it open in $\tau_1$, and in $\tau_2$?

Comment: @Muduri The closure of a set A is defined as $\overline{A} = \cap \{ C \text{ is closed } \mid A \subset C \}$. Since $K_1(A)=\overline{A}$, which is closed in $\tau_1$, $X \setminus K_1(A)$ is open in $\tau_1$. Now, $\tau_1 \subset \tau_2$, so it is also open in $K_2(A)$. How does this help me?

Comment: So what you just said can be understood as "$K_2(A)$ is the smallest closed set in $\tau_2$ that contains $A$" and "$K_1(A)$ is another closed set in $\tau_2$ that contains $A$". Is that clear for you?

Comment: @Muduri Yes, that is clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2$ we know that if a set $C$ is $\tau_1$-closed it is $\tau_2$-closed as well. (then $X\setminus C \in \tau_1$ so $X\setminus C \in \tau_2$ so $C$ is $\tau_2$-closed.) Now:

$$K_2(A) = \bigcap \{C\mid C \text{ is } \tau_2\text{-closed} ; A \subseteq C\} \subseteq \bigcap \{C\mid C \text{ is }\tau_1\text{-closed} ; A \subseteq C\} = K_1(A)$$

as intersections of larger families only can get smaller.

Comment: Or note that $K_1(A)$ is a $\tau_2$-closed subset in the family we take the intersection of in the definition of $K_2(A)$.